# When should a Teams Search Message Extension return the configuration URL and how does it receive the config results?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#respond-to-user-requests) page for Search Messaging Extensions indicates that "when a user performs a query" one of the valid responses includes setting the `composeExtension.type` to `config`. However, if I look at the [msgext-search-sso-config](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-search-sso-config/nodejs) sample it links to, the `config` response is happening when `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` is [called](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/e043a8577214c11ee2551e9a8145aa357dfd16c5/samples/msgext-search-sso-config/nodejs/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.js#L102), and not in response to the user performing a query (which I assume would be in `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` method).

Which is correct, in `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` or in `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery`?

If both are possibly correct, what causes the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` to be called? Is there a user action that triggers it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` and `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` methods serve different purposes in the context of a Teams app.

The `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` method is called when the user initially configures or updates the settings of the messaging extension. This is typically triggered by a user action such as clicking on the "Settings" option for the messaging extension. The response to this method should include the configuration page URL which will be opened in a task module for the user to configure the messaging extension settings.

On the other hand, the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` method is called when the user performs a search query using the messaging extension. The response to this method should include the search results that match the user's query.

So, to answer your question, both methods are correct but they are used in different scenarios. The `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` method is used for configuring the messaging extension settings, while the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` method is used for handling search queries.

The `composeExtension.type` property can be set to config in the response to the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl` method to indicate that a configuration page should be opened for the user to configure the messaging extension settings. This is not typically used in the response to the `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery` method.

Comment: You said that handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl is called when the user "initially configures or updates the settings of the messaging extension." How does a user do this? Is there a configuration button in the UI somewhere to trigger this flow?

Comment: Please have look into this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/search-extensions#handle-onquery-events

Comment: The UI shown in that document does not match what I see. When I click the "+" by the compose box, I do see a list of what I assume are MEs (mine included) but there is no ellipsis (like that page shows) or "Favorite" option (like that page shows). The only thing I can do from the + menu is open a search window to interact with the ME. How do I get to the UI where the "Settings" option is shown for my ME? My manifest has canUpdateConfiguration set to true for it, and I implement handleTeamsMessagingExtensionConfigurationQuerySettingUrl, but it never gets called.

Comment: Here is some sample related to ME-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately I didn't see anywhere in that code how I get to the UI in Teams where the "Settings" option is shown for my ME, like in the image on the page to which you originally linked?